# Bulk escape in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex is not so hot so apologies for the very newb question.

I'm using String.replace to change the string "../../libs/bootstrap/less" into just "bootstrap". Currently my regex looks like this:

```
myString.replace(\.\.\/\.\.\/libs\/bootstrap\/less/g, 'bootstrap);
```

I figure there has to be a better way to escape that path. Is it possible to specify a whole block of stuff to be escaped like /\"../../foo/bar/baz"/ ?

Comment: Why does it have to be a regular expression?

Comment: @Jack So it can replace *all* matches.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no global/block escape in regex. If you wanted to avoid the escaping in this instance you could alternatively do the following:

```
myString.replace(/([.]{2}[/]){2}libs[/]bootstrap[/]less/g, "bootstrap");
```

. and / don't need to be escaped when specified within a character set []

Comment: I ended up going with this: ([.]{2}\/){2}libs\/bootstrap\/less
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier *what* to quote in regular expressions you can use the following code:

```
RegExp.quote = function(str) {
     return str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
};
```

Then you apply it like so:

```
var expr = RegExp.quote('../../libs/bootstrap/less');
mystring.replace(new RegExp(expr, 'g'), 'bootstrap');
```

Comment: No need for the excess function, what OP needs is already in the language itself.

Comment: @SomeKittens OP is asking for a better way to escape the path, this answer is just more generic.

Comment: @MattWhipple You realize that we've been talking about Java**Script** this whole time right? There's no `Pattern` class.

Comment: @Jack whoops, sorry, should have looked at your code a bit closer